# Is my CDN or W3 Total Cache blocking the Facebook crawler?

Tags: facebook, w3-total-cache

Every new page I've added since yesterday (6) hasn't been able to pull data from the Facebook crawler. Debugger gives me Response code 200 and
error that must be fixed The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
errors that should be fixed Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Both of these are actually on the page.

Crawler tells me it's seeing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
<script>
loooong token(?) information
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="//content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried disabling/reenabling plugins that I've updated recently but that doesn't seem to d anything.

Ideas?

Comment: did you try turning w3 total cache off?

Comment: Not yet. If that's the problem would it be something that would fix it right away or does it need time because if the CDN?

Comment: CDN is normally used for external resources (like js plugins, for example), not sure why this would be a problem...

Comment: Okay, just disabled W3 and it didn't help.

Comment: Tried disabling all the plugins I've updated recently, leaving it like that for a few hours, then trying again and still nothing.

Comment: The CDN also blocks bot traffic and I think it may have classified it as a bot which is why I thought it might be that. Going to try adding the IPs from here to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#crawl to my whitelist. (CDN is SiteLock btw)

Comment: Okay, VERY happy to report that adding those IPs to the white list worked, so if anyone has a similar problem and you're using SiteLock that's your problem.